# cannot instantiate a class using a button

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, instantiation, awtrobot

I am trying to make a screen capturing program.

What I have is a transparent window, which will give the area  to be captured, with a button `capture` on it, and I am trying to instantiate a class `captureScreen` that works good when `captureScreen` is individually executed using a command prompt

I am trying to instantiate this `captureScreen` class when button `capture` is hit.

I have tried keeping this `class` on my `screenrecord.java`, putting the code in `event listener` also. In both these cases,I get these errors

```
AWTException,must be caught or declared
```

in

```
 Robot robot = new Robot();
```

and IOException in `BufferedImage image` line.

And keeping the `captureScreen.java` separate does nothing.`System.out.println("Start");` would even not print anything.

Here is my `screenrecord.java` code

```
public class screenrecord extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public screenrecord() {...
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if ("record".equals(e.getActionCommand())) {
            captureScreen a = new captureScreen();
            } 
    }   
}
```

And `captureScreen.java`, works fine individually.

```
public class captureScreen extends Object{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ...
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filename));
        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

All your suggestions, comments, advices are welcome and appreciated.
Please help me sort this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works on editing the `captureScreen.java` as,

```
public class captureScreen extends Object{

    public captureScreen() {
        ....
        filename = ".\\out.png";
        try{Robot robot = new Robot();
             ............ }
        catch(Exception e)  /* Catch Exceptions too  */
        {
            System.out.println("Error"+e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new captureScreen();
    }
}
```

Use main to instantiate another function.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be using try/catches. Those aren't errors so much as warnings. For instance, insert this around the code that has the AWTException:

```
try
{
    //code causing AWTException
    Robot robot = new Robot();
}
catch(AWTException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
}
```

And:

```
try
{
    //code causing IOException
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
}
```

Or combine both:

```
try
{
    //code causing AWTException or IOException
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
}
catch(AWTException e)
{
    System.out.println("Error"+e);
}
```

For further reading, this may help clarify exceptions:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/definition.html

Comment: I had googled and had used try - catch. But my problem isn't solved. I can't get my class instantiated. Even `"Start"` and `"Done"` in `captureScreen.java` doesn't get printed. Neither is the screen captured. `Donesss` get printed though from `screenrecord.java`

Comment: And also on catching the exception the try part doesn't work at all..that's not intended as this part is the most important.

Comment: Then I can't tell you what is going wrong. But the errors you described were obviously because you did not have try/catch statements. If there are other errors, they do not correspond to those errors and you have given us nothing to go on to help you out.

Comment: oh I got it working. And there were no other errors. I have posted an solution to the problem. And then removed the unnecessary code. Sorry if that confuses you. However thanks for helping in catching exceptions.:)