# extending an interface instead of implementing it

Tags: java

An interface definition (see below) has me confused:

```
public abstract interface Cursor {
    // hide details
}

public abstract interface Parcelable {
    // hide details
}

public interface Foo<T extends Bar> extends Cursor, Parcelable {
    // details omitted for brevity
};
```

1. I thought Java doesn't have multiple inheritance, so a class cannot `extends` more than one class.
2. On the other hand a class/interface can implement more than one interface. So why use `extends` instead of
   `implements`?

Comment: `class/interface can implement more than one interface` -- that's wrong on the part of interfaces - interface can not implement anything.

Comment: dont who have upvoted this question. strange

Comment: What's an abstract interface? Is that even valid Java syntax? Even if it is I'm pretty sure it is ignored.

Comment: André, check my answer, I discuss that syntax. tl;dr: it is valid and the keyword `abstract` is ignored (interfaces are implicitly abstract)

Comment: @BrunoReis that's exactly what I supsected. Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The rules for class/interface inheritance and implementation in Java 7 and below are as follows:

1. A class can only inherit from a single class (single inheritance)
2. A class might implement one or more interfaces (multiple interface implementation)
3. An interface might inherit from one or more interface (multiple interface inheritance)

When inheriting, you use the keyword `extends`, both when a class inherits from a class or an interface inherits from one or more interfaces. The term `extends` is to be understood as follows: *this class/interface is an extension of the its parent class/interface(s) -- it is everything the parent or parents are, and possibly more*.

When a class implements an interface (or more than one), you use the keyword `implements`. The term `implements` is to be understood as follows: *instances of this class are guaranteed to provide implementations for the methods of the parent interface(s)*.

Also, note that an `abstract class` uses the keyword `implements` when referring to a parent interface even if the abstract class itself does not implement the interface methods. This does not violate the principles stated above: there can only be instances of concrete classes, which must implement every declared method; therefore, any instance of that abstract class must be, in reality, an instance of a subclass implementing the methods from the interface. For example, this is perfectly valid: `abstract class AnAbstractClass implements Cursor {}`, even if Cursor declares lots of methods.

In your examples, the interface `Foo<T extends Bar>` inherits from two other interfaces, namely `Cursor` and `Parcelable`, which is an example of the 3rd point above. You use the keyword `extends` and not `implements` because the interface `Foo` is not implementing anything: the bodies of the methods of the parent interfaces are still not defined! If you had a class implementing those two parent interfaces, you'd do something like:

```
class AClass implements Cursor, Parcelable {
  @Override public // ... method signature and implementation
                   // for every method in Cursor and Parcelable
}
```

Also, note that you don't need to use the keyword `abstract` when declaring an interface: both the type and all its declared methods are implicitly abstract. The methods are also implicitly public (and cannot be declared with any other access modifier), since the purpose of an interface is precisely to declare the "public interface of an object", that is, which methods are guaranteed to be publicly available by any object implementing that interface.

---

Finally, some of the concepts described above are subject to be slightly changed in Java 8: in that release, you will be able to provide "default implementations" of methods right in the interface, in case the classes implementing the interfaces do not implement them. Things will be more similar to "class multiple inheritance": a class will be able to inherit implemented methods from multiple sources, which is not possible in Java 7 or below. For example (the syntax is not yet fixed):

```
interface NaturalNumber {
  void increment();
  default void add(int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      increment();
    }
  }
}

class NaturalNumberImplementation implements NaturalNumber {
  private int n = 0;
  @Override public void increment() { n++; }
}
```

This exists to allow you to neglect implementing some methods when you don't want to, while still being able to implement "better" versions of them when possible/needed. For instance:

```
class HighPerformanceNaturalNumberImplementation implements NaturalNumber {
  private int n = 0;
  @Override public void increment() { n++; }
  @Override public void add(int n) { this.n += n; }
}
```

Comment: Bruno,I havent got answer to my question, and cannot bring up my question as new, its now too down the list, please help me here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220399/cannot-instantiate-a-class-using-a-button

Answer (score 2):

**Answer 1.**

> A Java class can only extend one parent class. Multiple inheritance is
>   not allowed. Interfaces are not classes, however, and an interface can
>   extend more than one parent interface.

**Answer 2.**

You should always extend a class/interface when there is a parent child relationship. There should be no other reason for extending a class or an interface.

Answer (score 0):

### Interfaces:

- Interfaces extend interfaces.
- An interface can extend multiple interfaces.

### Classes:

- Clases extend classes.
- A class can only extend a single class.
- Only classes can implement interfaces.
- A class can implement multiple interfaces.