# rcaller IOException at runAndReturnResult

Tags: java, r, rcaller

I am trying to connect R from java using RCaller and here is my code

```
RCaller caller = new RCaller();
RCode code = new RCode();
caller.cleanRCode();
caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe");
code.addRCode ("source(\"D:/Data Mining workspaces/Workspace/CQpackage/First_try.R\")");
code.addRCode("myinput()");
caller.setRCode(code);
caller.runAndReturnResult("Done");
```

First_try.R contains a function defnition and the function is called **myinput()**

When i run this i am getting this error, i am not able to understand the reason. Please HElp

```
rcaller.exception.RCallerExecutionException: Can not run C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe. Reason: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:/Program": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at rcaller.RCaller.runAndReturnResult(RCaller.java:393)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `runOnly()` instead of `runAndReturnResult()`.

I suppose that `runAndReturnResult("done")` will run your code and return the value in the variable "done" which hasn't been initialized.

So, just use `runOnly()` which would just run your code. If you need to view your result, try redirecting your result to either any stream or console.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the space in the path. From the error it looks like that could be a problem. Also check out this question: [Error under bridge between R and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228224/error-under-bridge-between-r-and-java)

Comment: I tried escaping by doing Program\ files but its giving me illegal escape sequence error.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the line

```
caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/Rscript.exe");
```

by

```
caller.setRscriptExecutable("C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.0.2\\bin\\Rscript.exe");
```

in Windows. It seems it is a Java issue, not the one about RCaller.

Comment: tried,but did not work.i had to change the installation folder to make it work.